# Or Statement in Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

Column A has a list of Names
Table 4 has a table with a list of dates

I'm trying to get CF setup which looks up each Cell in Column A, matches it against the Table and if the date is within 90 days or has passed then it colours the cell.

I can get the statement to work in a standard cell:

```
=OR((VLOOKUP(A3,Table4,11,FALSE))-90<TODAY(),(VLOOKUP(A3,Table4,11,FALSE))<TODAY())
```

Cannot seem to get this to work in a CF for the whole column.

Comment: I'm confused by your two conditions. Can't the second condition only be true if the first condition is true. The first condition seems to cover both criteria both in your example and in the text of your question. What's the point of the second condition??

Answer (score 0):

Select A1 and with your formula as it stands (though change `A3`s to `A1`s) Applies to `=$A:$A`. If you don't want this applied to A1:A2 select this range and Clear Rules, Clear Rules from Selected Cells.

Answer (score -1):

Add a new column relative to your condition **if(MyCondition is verified; 1; 0)** and add your conditional formatting on this column based on 1 value.

```
= if(OR((VLOOKUP(A3,Table4,11,FALSE))-90<TODAY(),(VLOOKUP(A3,Table4,11,FALSE))<TODAY());1;0)
```